# asp.net sql order by certain value

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

hi i have an sql statement that returns rows from a table in descending order, the column i am ordering by is requestStatus. the requestStatus can be 3 values pending, approved and rejected . i would like to alter the sql if possible to order by pending then approved and then rejected. my sql statement is below. i am using asp.net razor view engine. can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
   var dbCommand2 = "SELECT * FROM LeaveRequests WHERE email = @0 ORDER BY WHERE requestStatus DESC";
   var rows1 = db.Query(dbCommand2, theUserName);
```

Comment: What is that WHERE after ORDER BY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CASE in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *, CASE requestStatus
   WHEN 'pending' THEN 0
   WHEN 'approved' THEN 1
   WHEN 'rejected' THEN 2
   END  AS requestStatusOrder
FROM LeaveRequests
WHERE email = @0
ORDER BY requestStatusOrder
```

Comment: You can just put the `case` directly in the `order by` and not have to add an additional column to the `select`.

Comment: Hi dave, great thanks for help , that works perfectly . i'll will also try your way gordon , thanks everyone for their help